# Does the order of kernel parameters matter when adding acpi_backlight=vendor?

Tags: grub2, ati, brightness

I am running 12.10 on an HP DV7-6197CA.

I had fan issues which I was able to correct by changing this line in GRUB;

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

So I have read that if I change that line to include `acpi_backlight=vendor` I will be able to adjust brightness, something I currently cannot do.

What I am wondering is can I still leave the `pcie_aspm=force` in the line? And should it be before or after `acpi_backlight` parameter?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

#### Order doesn't matter here.

Kernel parameters are separated by spaces and that's about it. Your line will become:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and is equivalent to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pcie_aspm=force quiet acpi_backlight=vendor splash"
```

or any other rearrangement of orders.

#### They're independent

Kernel parameters aren't related to each other. Specifying a parameter/value there for the PCIe subsystem are totally irrelevant for the ACPI/backlight subsystem. Just mix them up!